# Stop broken NFS mounts from locking a directory?

Tags: nfs

I have a somewhat interesting setup: A server with multiple remote NFS servers mounted in a folder, with that folder then being re-exported over Samba. Think of it as a share proxy, keeping all the shared folders in one place.

My issue though is that whenever one of the mounts goes down (server restarted, service restarted, external hard drive that the server was exporting removed, etc) any attempt to read the mount blocks forever. This also means that running `ls` in that directory freezes and users connecting over Samba also freeze. This has also caused a few times one of my cron jobs to block which almost crashed the server because it had hundreds of blocked processes. This is getting very annoying as I usually have to bring up a terminal that isn't waiting for `ls` to finish (can't cancel it), run `for i in *; do sudo umount -l -f $i; done;`, hope that it works, fix the issue, then remount everything.

Is there a way to mount an NFS share with the stipulation that if the connection fails for whatever reason (preferably with a retry period) then the mount un-mount's itself or at least doesn't block?

Comment: Can you post `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Normally when mounting NFS it's a good idea to have flags set similar to this:

```
bg,intr,soft
```

> ```
>    bg      If  the  first  NFS  mount  attempt times out, retry the mount in the 
>            background.  After a mount operation is backgrounded, all subsequent mounts
>            on the same NFS  server  will  be  backgrounded immediately, without first
>            attempting the mount.  A missing mount point is treated as a timeout, to
>            allow for nested NFS mounts.
>    soft    If  an  NFS  file operation has a major timeout then report an I/O error
>            to the calling program.  The default is to continue retrying NFS file
>            operations indefinitely.
>    intr    If  an  NFS  file  operation  has  a major timeout and it is hard mounted,
>            then allow signals to interupt the file operation and cause it to return
>            EINTR to the calling program.  The default is to not allow file operations
>            to be interrupted.
> ```

You can in addition set:

```
timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5
```

which should allow the NFS mount to timeout and make the directory inaccessible if the NFS server drops the connection rather then waiting in retries.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-client-config-options.html) for more information about NFS mount options

Comment: using only bg,intr,soft still leaves a hang of 120 seconds in Fedora 20. But adding timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5 makes it nice and quick. Thanks!

Comment: "The intr / nointr mount option is deprecated after kernel 2.6.25. Only SIGKILL can interrupt a pending NFS operation on these kernels, and if specified, this mount option is ignored to provide backwards compatibility with older kernels."
"This  option  is  provided for backward compatibility.  It is ignored after kernel 2.6.25."

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop where is that quote from? Can you give a link? Thanks.

Comment: @becko: The SIGKILL quote is from [the nfs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs) (just search down for 'nointr'). The newer versions, such as the one on my system now simply read "This option is provided for backward compatibility. It is ignored after kernel 2.6.25." [linky](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfs.5.html).