# how to prevent reboot being stopped by nfsmount?

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab

I can't imagine there isn't a simple strategy to solve this issue of stale nfs handles preventing a machine from shutting down normally, but I'm not sure what that would be. It's pretty annoying to have to force a reboot just because a wifi connection dropped out at some point while watching endless 'waiting for nfsmount' messages.

Comment: What's your distribution?

Comment: it's a gentoo based sabayon

Comment: Try add `-f` for netfs (modify the mount command), I couldn't remember the exact name of the service

Answer (score 3):

What are your mount options?

You should experiment with "`hard,intr`", or "`soft`" (with "`timeo`"), and possibly "`retrans`" depending on your client options. Using TCP instead of UDP may also help. The default is usually "`hard`".

Using "soft" is usually advised against, it can result in written data being lost. It's safe to use as read-only.

On latter linux kernels (2.6.25) NFS clients "intr" is deprecated, sigkill should just work. "`umount -f`" and "`umount -l`" can help.

See also [Stop broken NFS mounts from locking a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31979/stop-broken-nfs-mounts-from-locking-a-directory) and https://serverfault.com/questions/365149/how-do-i-forcibly-unmount-when-im-getting-stale-nfs-file-handles .